# Ionic: how show back button

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

In ionic i have a login page with this directive:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" class="home-background">
```

I use the hide-nav-bar to hide the navigation bar.

Then i transition to another page where i show the navigation bar and, in the template, i have:

```
<ion-view view-title="Chat">
```

Now the navigation bar is showed without back button (and it's ok this behaviour).

From this page i go to a detail page and i have:

```
<ion-view view-title="Chat Detail">
```

The problem now is that i don't see the back button. Inspecting the page i see:

Why there is hide class? How can i show the back button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an ion-nav-bar to your page and then an ion-nav-back-button. See example below. You can customize it whatever way you want. Below uses an ionicon chevron back arrow to get Android-style arrow.

```
<ion-view view-title="Chat Detail">
    <ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear" ng-click="back()">
            <i class="ion-chevron-left top-nav-bar-icon"></i>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

...
</ion-view>
```